# Issues connecting to Mobile Broadband - Ubuntu 14.10, Pantech UML290-VW

Tags: networking, 14.10, mobile-broadband

I have been successful in connecting to the Internet using a Pantech UML290-VW using the Mobile Broadband setup wizard (vzwinternet) in Ubuntu 14.10. My settings are as follows:

```
Number: *99#
Username: blank
Password: blank
APN: vzwinternet
```

My problem is that when the computer is restarted or shut down, upon booting again the connection refuses to work - immediately says "You have been disconnected." It is NOT set to connect automatically, although I tried this and the result was the same. If I unplug the dongle from the computer and then plug it back in (with the computer running), everything works as expected.

Any idea as to what might be causing this odd behaviour? I do not see any obvious error messages anywhere, not sure if there is some log information available.

**Additional info:**

- Auto-login is set, so I cannot check the behaviour there
- Output of `ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` is:

  `AndroidAP` (to be able to connect to the Internet without the dongle))

  `Verizon 4G LTE Contract 1` (the problem connection)

Output of `Verizon 4G LTE Contract 1` is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10142892/

Output of `dsmesg` : http://paste.ubuntu.com/10142950/

**After Suggested Changes & Reboot**

After rebooting, the connection is visible in the networking drop-down menu but when I select it, immediately disconnected (same as initial problem). Before trying to connect I copied the command output requested earlier: [dmesg before unplugging dongle](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10144333/) and [dmesg after unplugging/re-inserting](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10144345/). Also, here are the contents of `Verizon 4G LTE Contract 1` after rebooting: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10144371/

Comment: On the `dsmesg` output the dongle is referenced on line 99, Pantech UML290

Comment: Could you edit the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Verizon 4G LTE Contract 1` file and remove the line `permissions=user:tevfd:;` and set `autoconnect=true` instead of `false` and reboot?  (and report back, please?)  ;-)

Comment: Done. I'm actually working on it remotely, the machine is about 30 minutes from my location - so if it doesn't come back on, we will know it did not work lol

Comment: Looks like my TeamViewer connection did not come back up, so I am assuming that it is still offline after reboot. I will try to head out there shortly, within the hour.

Comment: I should still be here after that time...  Sorry, but I thought we were onto something!

Comment: I'll head out right now. It sounds promising... even if the user can connect from the drop-down without having to unplug and reinsert the dongle every time, I'm happy. Wondering if the permission part might help with that somehow. We'll see, brb

Comment: @Fabby see updates, essentially no change. I did notice that the connection file was different than it was before reboot, the autoconnect field is gone. I also saw a few errors at the end of `dmesg` before I unplugged and re-inserted the dongle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've hit a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/848164) that is fixed in Debian but not released in Ubuntu yet.

Subscribe to the bug tracking list so you will be informed when a bug fix is released...

The only two thing you can do for now is the work-around you've already found:

1. Remove and re-insert the modem physically.
2. After the modem goes online (and fails), disconnect from the connection (don't unplug the modem), disable mobile broadband, re-enable it, and connect again. [Credit for this workaround: SF](https://askubuntu.com/users/82863/sf)

Comment: And please, even when the answer is "there seems to be a bug", don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  :-(

Comment: First, really appreciate all of your help! But the bug seems to be a bit different than what I am seeing. It's not that it will not autoconnect, it is that it will not connect *at all* unless I unplug it and plug it back in after the machine boots. It keeps saying "Disconnected. You are now offline" when I attempt to connect. Would this still be the same bug?

Comment: Reading it again... IMHO, yes.  From the comments: "autoconnection for mobile broadband is not yet supported."

Comment: Right, but again it's that it will not connect *period* unless I do the unplug, replug deal. Not that it simply does not connect automatically.

Comment: It is my considered (and reconsidered) opinion... If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0 and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...

Comment: :D :D :D  Telepathy!

Comment: Thanks, familiar with Stack Exchange ;) Accepted your answer AND gave you a +1 for all your help, but please let me know if you come across any other potential causes for this. While the bug does sound similar, it is not 100% what I am seeing. I may also try some of the scripts people have added to that page. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, the text of the bug description got me a workaround that works fine. After the modem goes online (and fails), disconnect from the connection (don't unplug the modem), disable mobile broadband, re-enable it, and connect again. In my case it established the connection just fine after that.

Comment: @SF: Good one!  Added[ (and credited you!)  **;-)**